# Showing which option is selected in rails dropdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, html-select

I have this code:

```
%tr
  %th Parent      
  %td
    %select{ :name => "firstlevel_id", :value => "#{@s.firstlevel_id}" }
      - Firstlevel.find(:all).each do |f|
        %option{ :value => "#{f.id}" } #{f.title}
```

but even if the `firstlevel_id` is already one of the id's in the options list, it doesn't show it as selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the select_tag to generate the html , and options_for_select to generate the html :

```
select_tag :firstlevel_id, options_for_select( Firstlevel.all.map{|l| [l.title, l.id] }, @s.try(:firstlevel_id) )
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You can use [`select_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-select_tag) helper to create `select` tag and control selected value.
2. You can also set `selected` attribute on proper `option` tag:

   ```
   %select{:name => "firstlevel_id"}
     - FirstLevel.find(:all).each do |f|
       %option{:value => f.id, :selected => f.id == @s.firstlevel_id} #{f.title}
   ```

I would prefer the first solution.